# Can't create Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

So I have tried to create a Laravel project in pretty much every conceivable way and nothing works.

The attempts I made:

- `composer global require laravel/installer`

  - -> ./composer.json is not writable
- `composer require laravel/installer`

  - -> cannot create cache directory ...
- `sudo composer global require laravel/installer`

  - -> Do not run Composer as root

The second and third attempts printed warnings but completed.
In no case, I can use `laravel new myproject` to create a new project (as described on laravel.com as well as everywhere else.

When I then use

```
vendor/laravel/installer/laravel new myproject
```

I get the following error twice

> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
>   Error creating resource: [message]
>   fopen(http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip): failed to open stream:
>   Unable to find the socke     t transport "http" - did you forget to
>   enable it when you configured PHP?
>   [file]
>   /home/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
>   [line] 324

I am sure that PHP is configured correctly since I was able to create a Laravel project a while ago (with a lot of complications)

When I use

```
sudo vendor/laravel/installer/laravel new myproject
```

I get a couple of warnings that I shouldn't use sudo and although the creation of the project works, I can't open it with PHPStorm

The pwd has 777 rights.

I am seriously stuck... I just want to create a Laravel project, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing something odd or you've borked the server. Why don't you have permission to create directories and modify `composer.json`? Are you attempting to run these commands in a folder your user doesn't have rights to?

Comment: The working directory is in my home folder and I created it with mkdir without changing the owner or using sudo

Comment: you tried every way but using composer to create a laravel project

Comment: @Maaaaa just try out `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject` but make sure to install composer.

Answer (score 1):

For **laravel v8.0** you could try this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <projectname>
```

For **laravel 7.0** that should work:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 <projectname>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

`composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject`