# cant install laravel in composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Tried creating a new project on a corporate proxy and suddenly composer cant create a laravel project.

"curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Connection timed out after 10001 millisec
onds"

been trying different stackoverflow solutions but none of them solves my problem.

running "[composer diagnose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJSI.png)"

Comment: "composer cant create a laravel project" - what does that mean? What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: tahe a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442233/cant-create-laravel-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by running

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@IP:port && php composer.phar install
```

source:
[Composer cannot download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268093/composer-cannot-download-files)

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try this,

Try clearing Composer's cache by running composer clear-cache remove composer.lock and composer install